# Add Primary Key column at the end of an Index

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, clustered-index, mariadb-10.1

If I have a table with the following primary key:

`PRIMARY KEY (id)`

And I want to query documents written by someone (e.g. display a preview of the latest 20), sorted by their "id", so I created an index:

`INDEX from_id (from, id)`

Is the "id" at the end of this index redundant because it ends with the primary key?
If yes, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In InnoDB*, every "secondary" index (that is, index other than "PRIMARY") automatically adds the columns of the PK.

These are 'identical':

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),  INDEX(from, id)
PRIMARY KEY(id),  INDEX(from)
```

You *could* even do

```
PRIMARY KEY(from, id),  INDEX(id)
```

This combo is beneficial when `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but you often do a range on `from`.  Now the rows are "clustered" together, thereby being more efficient to fetch.  Meanwhile, `INDEX(id)` keeps `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy -- since it needs to know where it left off.

I assume you are doing:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE `from` = '...'
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 20;
```